# Created a Bootable USB Drive to Install Ubuntu.. What next?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I created a bootable Ubuntu USB drive (no CD drive on ultrabook) on Windows so I can install the OS. When I boot from the USB drive, I get a terminal with "grub." I have no idea how to even begin the installation of Ubuntu. Google has yielded no results and I really want to get this up and running as soon as possible.

How do I install the OS from grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely shouldn't happen. You should get a beautiful menu to select if you either want to install Ubuntu or test it. But anyway, we can do it through the grub menu. Run the following commands:

`set root=(hd0,msdos1)`

I'm considering your flash drive has only one partition here.

`linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper noprompt noeject quiet splash`

`initrd /casper/initrd.lz`

`boot`

And that, in the best scenario, should boot Ubuntu Live.

Comment: When I enter the second line, I get unknown file system

Comment: Figured it out! Usb was not formatted as fat32. Thanks for your help!