# When i boot from an ubuntu usb drive i get the grub prompt

Tags: usb, rufus

I created the bootable usb drive with Rufus but PC will not boot to ubuntu.

It seems others have had this problem but not in the hast 5 years.   Should i follow the grub commands given here?
[Created a Bootable USB Drive to Install Ubuntu.. What next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720833/created-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-ubuntu-what-next)

I have checked the BIOS and Secure Boot is disabled.  Boot from USB is enabled.

Machine seems to boot from usb but just delivers the grub prompt.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your USB device is hd1. Try replacing **hd0** with **hd1**. If you have 2 hdd or ssd, go with **hd2**

Comment: I think you have insight into the problem but i don't know how to do what you suggest.  You are right in that the machine came with Windows 10 on a 1TB HDD.  I have added a ssd on the M.2 port.  I want to load Ubuntu from the USB drive onto the ssd.  

The USB drive has been made with Rufus.  If you can tell me how to make the machine boot from the USB drive and install Ubuntu on the ssd i'd be extremely grateful.       Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making your USB with Balena Etcher.

Comment: As you said, you have a 1Tb HDD and a SSD. So the USB might be the 3rd device. So, go with **hd2**. I think rest steps are correct. If anything doesn`t help, go with installation using HDD or SSD. Follow this answer to install Ubuntu via HDD or SSD. Ask if you need help.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1300287/1158731

Comment: 1. Balena Etcher doesn't work for me.  Etcher goes through the process but produces a USB stick that is non-bootable and the 32GB stick is now recognised by windows as a 3.8MB stick.  That issue isnt fixed by formatting.  Interestingly Rufus can reset the usb stick to 32GB.

Comment: 2.  askubuntu.com/a/1300287/1158731 doesn't seem to take me to a solution either.  Grub is installed so i didnt reinstall it.  Grub recognises the HDD partitions and also the SSD as hd2,gpt2.  But if i type "root = (hd2,2)" or "root = (hd2,gpt2)" grub returns that root isnt recognised as a command.

Comment: ... i really really need help.

Comment: I've been trying to burn with Ubunutu 20.04.1 LTS. I'm now downloading Ubuntu 20.10 to see if either Rufus or Balenba Etcher can make that work.

Comment: I've made progress! I used Ubuntu 20.10 instead of the LTS version.  Burnt it with Balena Etcher.  Now seems to be loading Ubuntu. Phew!  Thanks for your help.  I seem to be progrssing now. I'll beg for more help if I get stuck again.

Comment: Ubuntu now loaded and running. It seems the iso image downloaded from Ubuntu caused the problem. For me the iso file for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is bad.  The image for Ubuntu 20.10 is fine.  I will try to report this to Canonical.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu now loaded and running. It seems the iso image downloaded from Ubuntu caused the problem. For me the iso file for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is bad. The image for Ubuntu 20.10 is fine. I will try to report this to Canonical

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this thread with a similar problem.

The Ubuntu drive was just working earlier today to boot on my parents' PC (they keep complaining how slow it is so I decided to give them a trial), but then I just got a grub boot prompt and don't know enough linux commands yet to poke around from there.

I had a second flash drive plugged in which was getting priority. I forgot it was set up as a rescue drive and not just storage for a pile of tools and PortableApps. Unplugged it, rebooted, live OS booted no problem

Just leaving this here in case it helps someone